# Issue with including a page and mod_rewrite

Tags: php, regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a little problem including files and then rewriting the url with mod_rewrite.
I'm including pages in my index.php using $_GET. My code there looks like that:

```
if(isset($_GET['page']))
{
    $file = "./pages/$page.php";
    if (file_exists($file))
    {
        include($file);
    }
```

This piece of code works fine and I'am able to access all pages as i like using domain.tld/index.php?page=example. But I want to use mod_rewrite on it so I can access the pages via domain.tld/Example. And that's my problem. Whenever I open this link, I can see the content of this page, so it works, but there is no css and when I'm opening the .css file, it's displaying me a 404 error. After using print_r on $_GET, my $_GET['page'] looks like that: Array ( [page] => css/menu.css ). So php is interpreting the link to my css page as an value for including a page. Can anyone help me at this topic, iI'm quite confused how to deal with it...

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews


ErrorDocument 401 /401.php
ErrorDocument 403 /403.php
ErrorDocument 404 /404.php
ErrorDocument 500 /500.html

RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /timetable
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?page=$1 [L,QSA]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ $1.php [L]`
```

And sorry for my bad english in advance ^^

Comment: Can you show your existing rewrite rules?

Comment: `Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
 
ErrorDocument 401 /401.php
ErrorDocument 403 /403.php
ErrorDocument 404 /404.php
ErrorDocument 500 /500.html
 
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /timetable
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?page=$1 [L,QSA]
 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ $1.php [L]` Thats my complete .htaccess

Comment: Please edit that into your question using the edit button under your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`RewriteCond` is only applied to closest `RewriteRule` only. Your first rule is rewriting every file and directory also which you need to avoid by using `RewriteCond`.

Replace your rules with this:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews

ErrorDocument 401 /401.php
ErrorDocument 403 /403.php
ErrorDocument 404 /404.php
ErrorDocument 500 /500.html

RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /timetable/

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ $1.php [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?page=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: Ah, thanks for the quick answer, forgot to use conditions on this rule. :)